# Getting TypeError: "POST data should be bytes or an iterable of bytes. It cannot be str." while following simply online example

Tags: python, selenium, python-3.2

I'm attempting to learn some automated testing, but have hit a wall right at the start.

I'm getting the error in the title when I try to run the very simple example from this web site: https://gist.github.com/1126917

Here's the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
assert "Python" in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
elem.send_keys("selenium")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
assert "Google" in driver.title
driver.close()
```

I've tried debugging but I didn't have any luck with that. I can't even tell what piece of data is typed wrong. Keep in mind that I just installed most of this into my environment, so I haven't been messing around much.

Relevant info:

- Python 3.2.3
- Selenium 2

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is the error you're getting, exactly?

Answer (score 1):

[As stated in the docs](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PythonBindings), Selenium bindings for Python are only compatible with Python 2.6 and 2.7.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I looked around in the docs and I'm a bit embarrassed to have missed that. Oh well, have to learn somehow. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The online example is in Python 2, where `str` and `bytes` are essentially the same thing.

Have a look at [this](http://blog.ludovf.net/python-str-unicode/) or better [this](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) for explanation.

Briefly, in Python 3 you need explicit conversion between `str` (which is a Unicode string) and `bytes` (which is an encoded string). That's one of the major differences between Python 2.x and 3.x.

Taking [Tim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10745462/1258041) into account, the error is most likely to happen somewhere inside `selenium` module, so you should probably install Python 2.7 to work with Selenium.